# HTML - aligning radio buttons and text

Tags: html, browser, radio-button, alignment, vertical-alignment

Say you've got two simple table cells next to each other.
One contains a radio button and text. The other one contains just text.

The radio button's size is set to 16x16 pixels (don't ask me why, assume that it just is).
The font size is 12 pixels.

How do you make both labels and the radio button to line up consistently in all major browsers along (or reasonably close to) the vertical middle of the table row?

Sample HTML to get you started:

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.radio {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0px;
}

.blah {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" class="radio" />
      <span class="blah">O</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="blah">O</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In my installed versions of IE, Opera, Firefox and Chrome, the above renders like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3110371/work/aligntest.png)

The result I'm expecting to see is the one displayed on that image by...  ...IE? Seriously?

The rest look close enough, but any attempts I made to line up the text made it always look awful in at least 2 of the 4 browsers.

Comment: Side note: why are you using tables for this? That's so 90s ;) Use floating divs instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "vertical-align:middle" found [this short explanation](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) by Gavin Kistner, which is useful. I tried out the final suggestion on that page, which seems to render repectably in Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

What I did was add `td{ line-height:1.5em }` - see the link for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix is to make the `font-size:12px;` of the td and `width:16px;height:16px;` of the radio equal.

2 examples:

```
td {
  font-size: 12px;
}
input[type=radio] {
  width: 12px; /* resize radio */
  height: 12px;
}
```

and

```
td {
  font-size: 16px; /* resize font-size */
}
input[type=radio] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: @Gert G:Interesting, guess the moz css rendering is different from webkit. Back to tinkering.

Comment: this tip worked great for me in FF and Chrome... have not tested in IE yet (I am not using tables)... Thanks!

Comment: This is not going to look pretty on high DPI screens :/

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" />
</td>
<td>
  <span class="blah">O</span> <!-- text -->
</td>
<td>
  <span class="blah">O</span> <!-- text2 -->
</td>
```

Why don't you put the text in its own column.

Comment: that works until he wants to introduce padding, at which point the first span will appear to be its own element, rather than associated with the radio button

Comment: give it a class than with padding:0;

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to add a nested table to the first of your two cells, and put the radio button and first span in two cells (within the nested table)

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td> 
      <table><tr><td><input type="radio" class="radio" /></td>
      <td><span class="blah">O</span></td></tr></table>
    </td> 
    <td> 
      <span class="blah">O</span> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Because tables were invented as a design tool. ;)

Comment: The outer table was actually fairly justified (in the original problem that I derived this example from) as I needed to arrange the content into an actual grid.

So I'd still like to stay away from these inner "hack tables" :)

But anyway, I already got an answer that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick shots in the dark:

- Give the radio input element it's own table cell? Then at least the text's should line up with each other.
- Put `vertical-align:middle;` to `td` instead of `.radio`? May still cause problems, because the baseline of the text in the cell with the radio input element may still be determined by the input element...